# How to sniff these kind of request?

Tags: php, zend-framework, tcp

im using a script that fetch google content (google snippet) on Zend Framework
since the script is not suported anymore by the DEV team 
i need  to debug the script & i would like to know how to sniff the return of the google query :

exemple of the code:

```
public function fetchContent($keyword)
{
$client = $this->getClient()
->setUri('https://www.google.com/search')
->setParameterGet(array(
'q'       => $keyword,
'ie'      => 'UTF-8'
));
```

when i use tcp dump for debug the google query :
`tcpdump -n -i venet0 -s 0 -w /tmp/output.txt`

i dont see anywhere the request made to google
the tcp dump output is here
http://pcapperf.appspot.com/view?hash_str=2b246ed29fb84a93504bca47ef3fb0f0

i can see in the script that the request is made to google & does fetch content 
how can i intercept this data please ?

does it related to UDP & not TCP ?

does my tcpdump sniffing does not contain enough parameter ?

thx you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can't sniff https as normal way

**you should change**

```
https://www.google.com/search
```

**to**

```
http://www.google.com/search
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you have the right device? maybe try

```
tcpdump -i any
```

Also, monitor

```
netstat -an
```

to see if a connection is actually made to Google

also, why are you trying https ? maybe you are having issues with SSL requests ?

Comment: thx you Jeff for the answer, yes that the correct device (its a vps) in same time i  think you right i didnt know that it does not sniff https, do you know the correct way to sniff https please with tcpdump please ?

Comment: ok it say on tcpdump to add this parameter:-s 0 to capture all data, i just need to decode it

Comment: http://www.google.com/search is not working anymore , we are oblige to use https to get the output (new rule)